# Bluetooth on Android - how to connect to the CORRECT bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid, rfcomm

I'm writing a program that speaks with an external accessory over rfcomm.
My problem is that I don't know what the correct way of identifying my device is.
the way I do it now is like this:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                .getBondedDevices();
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals(MY_DEVICE_NAME)) {
                this.myDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
```

This method however relies on the name of the device which to me seems dirty and bad :)
is there a better way to do this?
I tried looking at all the methods of [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) but none seemed to help - is the name really the best way to do it?
I saw that in some places people say that I should use UUIDs but that is used to open the socket to the device once I have it:

```
            _socket = myDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Devices of the same kind/functionality and/or brand will usually have a similar name. For example, all [RN-41 devices from Roving Networks](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/rn-41.php) have the following name:

```
FireFly-XXXX
```

where `XXXX` is the last 4 digits of the device's address. That means you can use the following to connect to *any* of them:

```
        if (device.getName().startsWith("FireFly-")) {
            this.myDevice = device;
            break;
        }
```

This is exactly what I do in my app and haven't found any more reliable/consistent way to do it. As a generalization, you should be able to use a regular pattern if the name in the devices you are interested in is any more complex than the example above.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now as well, but I was hoping there is a better way that doesn't rely on the name...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myDevice.getAddress()` to get the bluetooth device address and compare, it will always be unique (unlike name)

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a specific class of devices (let's say a specific model of jabra headsets) so the address is not known beforehand. I was thinking something like device.getBluetoothClass() but I'm not sure how it works...

Comment: the getBluetoothClass will get you the type of device and what type of service the device supports. This is useful to further filter to the kind device. But ultimately to connect to a device you need to then get its bluetooth address and connect.

Comment: So the answer is that the class is the way to identify the device? The documentation says: BluetoothClass is useful as a hint to roughly describe a device (for example to show an icon in the UI), but does not reliably describe which Bluetooth profiles or services are actually supported by a device. Accurate service discovery is done through SDP requests, which are automatically performed when creating an RFCOMM socket with createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID) and listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(String, UUID)
I think that means that it's not enough - it's rough - I need a way to identify!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use BluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass() for at narrowing down which devices might be relevant.

BluetoothClass.getMajorDeviceClass() will tell you roughly what kind of device it is - a phone, a computer, an audio or video device, or whatever.
BluetoothClass.hasService() further specifies some capabilities of the device.

Within each of the major classes, some minor classes are defined - what kind of computer / audio-video device / phone / health equipment etc. it is.

Also, on recent versions of the Android platform (API level 15+), you can query for the service records of a device, without having to connect to it.  See BluetoothDevice.fetchUuidsWithSdp() and BluetoothDevice.getUuids().